# html/jquery how to hover div with its child when mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my idea is to create this: 
https://blog.hubspot.com/hs-fs/hubfs/dubsat-contact-us-cities.gif?t=1490783992392&width=690&height=585&name=dubsat-contact-us-cities.gif

but the text has to be in div's with a picture not just fading in and fading out pictures. heres my shot:

```css
#first{
    position: absolute;

}
#second{
    position: absolute;

    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
}
.text-box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.text-box:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
 <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    </head>
    <h1 id="third">Kontaktai</h1>
    <!-- <div class="image">-->

    <div id="first" onmouseenter="showSecondImage()" onmouseleave="hideSecondImage()">
        <h4 class="text-box ">whyyyy</h4>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://kids.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/kids/photos/animals/Mammals/H-P/photoark-lion.png.adapt.945.1.jpg" >
    </div>

    <div id="second">
        <h4 class="text-box">why its not working</h4>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/06/09/16/03BB5E5A0000044D-3117010-image-a-25_1433862086692.jpg" >
    </div>
    <script>
        $(".unbinded").unbind();
        function  showSecondImage() {
            document.getElementById('second').style.opacity=1;
        }
        function  hideSecondImage() {
            document.getElementById('second').style.opacity=0;
        }
    </script>
```

why is not not working properly? i though i need to unbind onmouseenter and onmouseleave eventlisteners and bind the picture to listen when mouse enters..  any answers appreciated, im new to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS alone by hiding `#second` initially, then triggering it to show when you hover either `#first` or `#second`

```css
#first {
  position: absolute;
}

#second {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-box:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#first:hover + #second, #second:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="third">Kontaktai</h1>

<div id="first">
  <h4 class="text-box ">whyyyy</h4>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://kids.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/kids/photos/animals/Mammals/H-P/photoark-lion.png.adapt.945.1.jpg">
</div>

<div id="second">
  <h4 class="text-box">why its not working</h4>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/06/09/16/03BB5E5A0000044D-3117010-image-a-25_1433862086692.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i need to hover the image with all context in it (the whole div) when mouse enters and to show the div that is under him with the context. when mouse leaves the second div i need to show the first one and hide the second one. this hover .text-box just hovers the text

Comment: @EgidijusBrazaitis oh sorry I think I misunderstood your post. Like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Rpqmov

Comment: First image is broken link, but probably meant to be this: http://www.mostamazingworlds.com/upload/media/entries/2016-10/21/18-1-c946e822e78baea38d933695708ee194.jpg

Comment: @EgidijusBrazaitis np. BTW you can do that in CSS, too - no need for JS. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like Coker says, You can do it only with CSS, and the pseudo-selector :hover.

```css
            div
            {
                width:500px;
                height: 200px;
                cursor: pointer;
                background-size: cover;
                transition: background-image .6s ease-in-out;
            }
            .first
            {
                background-image: url("http://apopka.uhcpqdoe6fq4wtztv.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/spring-daffodils_2845661b.jpg");
            }
            .second
            {
                background-image: url("http://www.twitrcovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Winter-snow-l.jpg");
            }
            .first:hover
            {
                background-image: url("http://trucosparadecorar.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/oto%C3%B1o2.jpg");
            }
            .second:hover
            {
                background-image: url("http://cadenaser00.epimg.net/ser/imagenes/2016/06/20/sociedad/1466419875_801497_1466420115_noticia_normal.jpg");
            }
            div p
            {
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 24px;
                position: relative;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
                top: 43%;
            }
            div:hover .hidden
            {
                display:block;
            }
            .hidden
            {
                display:none;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .shadow:hover
            {
                background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hola</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="first">
            <div class="shadow">
                <p>Spring of Field</p>
                <p class="hidden">Spring is wonderful, unless for allergic people that die each year by.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            <div class="shadow">
                <p>Snow world</p>
                <p class="hidden">Go in winter, after the snow doesn't exist anymore.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```